# Map two database tables in a single model file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a two tables users and user_new. Both these tables have the same schema :

```
id INT
name VARCHAR(20)
email address  VARCHAR(20)
age  INT
address  VARCHAR(20)
```

I want to map these two tables into a single model file User in the model file in Rails.

Can anyone suggest me a good way to perform this activity in Rails. Let me know if any clarification is required?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution would be to change your schema to STI (single table inheritance). Add a column "type" to User and you can create different user. With STI you always can interact with one user object and not with a strange association.. To get an idea of STI check out following links:

1- http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails

2- http://www.railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations

3- http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance

Original answer above by Mattherick on one of my questions.

4- [A Free screencast from TeachMeToCode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0KH_9ikZiA_)

For example:

```
# /app/models/sports/sport.rb
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Methods, variables and constants
end


# /app/models/sports/probasketball.rb
class ProBasketball < Sport
  # Methods, variables and constants
end


# /app/models/sports/profootball.rb
class ProFootball < Sport
  # Methods, variables and constants
end



# /app/models/sports/baseball.rb
class Baseball < Sport
  # Methods, variables and constants
end
```

Comment: I learnt about STI. But in using STI , i think i am required to create a base class(like in your example 'Sport'). Also , we need to add 'type' column in the base class. Is there any way by which i can avoid creation of the base table?

Comment: have you checked the screencast #4 ? he making an example for users , watch it maybe you find something new

Answer (score -1):

You can create new file `user_new` in `app/models` with:

```
class UserNew < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection 'other_database'
  set_table_name "user_new"
end
```

Put in `database.yml`:

```
other_database:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: pudra
  username: root
  encoding: utf8
# use your connection params
```

And now you have a two models, connected to different databases. Then u can:

```
UserNew.all.each do |user_new|
  User.create(name: user_new.name, email: user_new.email, age: user_new.age)
end
```

If these table in one database, u can only:

```
class UserNew < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "user_new"
end
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new file user_new in the app/model folder , can i add that class into a single file. basically i want to keep only one file which should contain information about both these files.